# How scale raster without image smoothing

Tags: paperjs

With paperjs, how can a raster be scaled with image smoothing disabled? I need to scale pixel art.

Something akin to `canvas.imageSmoothingEnabled = false` (canvas) or `image-rendering: pixelated` (CSS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Paper.js` version `0.11.8`, [raster.smoothing](http://paperjs.org/reference/raster/#smoothing) was added exactly for this purpose.
You have to set it to `false` if you don't want the image to be blured when scaled up.

```
var raster = new Raster({
    source: 'http://assets.paperjs.org/images/marilyn.jpg',
    smoothing: false
});

raster.position = view.center;
raster.scale(10);
```